# Objects are not valid as a React child (again)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know there is a bunch of the same questions but I really don't understand how to approach this differently than this. I really need an array of objects to be inside a map, I made an array to map it but need to find different info to show so I made a find on array of objects inside the map. How else I can do this other than with objects?!?

I have an array :

```
itemInfoObjTemp = ["lst_price", "qty_available", "qty_availible_diff"]
```

and I have an array of objects:

```
itemInfoObjTemp2 =
    Array [
      Object {
        "field_description": "Javna cijena",
        "id": 2089,
        "name": "lst_price",
      },
      Object {
        "field_description": "Fizička zaliha",
        "id": 3774,
        "name": "qty_available",
      },
      Object {
        "field_description": "Reserved Qty",
        "id": 10970,
        "name": "qty_availible_diff",
      },
    ]
```

and I'm trying to show the `field_description` as label, but I'm getting:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,
> field_description, name}). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead.

```
              {itemInfoObjTemp.map((item, index) => (
                <Text key={index}>
                  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    {itemInfoObjTemp2.find(item2 =>
                      item2.name === item
                        ? item2.field_description
                        : item
                    )}
                    :
                  </Text>{' '}
                  {itemInfoObj[item].toString()}
                </Text>
              ))}
```

all this info is dynamic from API, including object properites, so no hardcoding is possible.

Comment: In an example such as: `someArray.find(someFn)`, the `someFn` is a function that is expected to return a boolean for each element of the 'someArray` array. The `.find` will return the `someArray` element which first matches the criteria set by `someFn` function. It returns the actual element as-is. So, if the element is an object, then `.find` returns an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `find()` docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

They state that it "returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function". This means when you call `find()`, you're receiving an Object back.

Instead, try out something like:

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    {itemInfoObjTemp2.find(item2 => item2.name === item)?.field_description}
</Text>
```

Comment: I feel ashamed... I just needed:                          `itemInfoObjTemp2.find( item2 => item2.name === item).field_description` it is one of those days...

Comment: No shame at all. We all forget how JavaScript works sometimes :)

I'd suggest adding the optional chaining on the returned object. In your original code, it looked like you weren't sure that there was always going to be an object returned. If there is not an object returned, you'll get an error trying to access `.field_description` on `undefined`. Optional chaining will fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it with index:

```
                  {itemInfoObjTemp.map((item, index) => (
                    <Text key={index}>
                      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                        {itemInfoObjTemp2[index].field_description}:
                      </Text>{' '}
                      {itemInfoObj[item].toString()}
                    </Text>
                  ))}
```

But this is ridiculous. This will only work if arrays are of the same length and in the right order. In my case they by luck will always, but I really should have other safer options...

Comment: You don't need to directly access the index. Your code was almost correct, just using the incorrect Array function.

Comment: How is it ridiculous? The original code didn't use `find` correctly, and you're reaching directly into an array of objects. It's also not clear that this is actually works as intended--`index` is sequential, if the array of objects is ordered differently than the array of strings seems like this'd be broken.

Comment: @DaveNewton They are not ordered differently. I made a mistake when creating a question, made it manually not copied... IM gonna crawl back to my hole now...

Comment: (If it's ordered the same then what do you need `find` for at all?) I'm two holes over if you need anything else ;) Safer in the holes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Just in case they won't be, like I say it's all API dynamic data, only thing is certain, is that info will be there in both. So find is better then index. Thanks for the help!